# Opening socket to outside computer with Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am using the following code to open a socket on my computer.  When I go to my_ip:5000 on my computer the program responds.  However, when I use another computer, nothing happens.

```
HOST = 'my_ip'                 # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 8000              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the firewall or not.  When I start up the test server in django using `manage.py runserver my_ip:8000` I am able to connect to the machine from a different computer.  I'm not sure what is causing me not to be able to connect from another computer using the code above...

Comment: ping my_ip works from that machine?

Comment: Are you trying to reach the server from outside your local network? If that's the case, check if you've forwarded the port correctly. If you're trying to access it from a computer in the same network, be sure to use the internal IP and not the external.

Comment: Yes, when I type `my_ip` in to the machine the above code is running on it works.  However when I use a different machine, nothing.

Comment: I'm trying to access it from outside the network

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By setting HOST to `'my_ip'`, you may listen to a private IP that only resolves to your computer *for* your computer. The best-known example is `127.0.0.1`. Instead, pass an empty string (`HOST=''`) to listen to *any* requests coming in at the specified port. Make sure to use the same port number, i.e. either 5000 or 8000, on both machines.

Also, check whether a firewall between the computers (or installed on one of them) prevents the connection.

To test whether your computer is reachable in principle, run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in a directory without private information on the server and try to reach the webserver started with that from the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried the `-m SimpleHTTPServer` and it worked on the local machine but not a remote machine.  In Django, when I run `manage.py runserver my_ip:8000` I am able to use a remote machine to access files.  Could this be an issue with the firewall?  I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: @AlexisK Yes, it could definitely be the local firewall. The result of  running django and running the SimpleHTTPServer should definitely be the same though. Are you certain the IP is correct? By the way, you may want to use a packet dumper such as [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (potentially on both machines) to debug the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I through running the django and SimpleHTTPServer should be the same but for some reason it is not :(  I tried SimpleHTTPServer  in the exact folder that I ran runserver in and it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexisK That strongly indicates the firewall. Does it work if you temporarily disable the Windows firewall? What does wireshark display?

Comment: I turned off the firewall and same behavior.  runserver works as expected SimpleHTTPServer does not.  ;(   SimpleHTTPServer says "Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000"

Comment: @AlexisK If you start runserver with `0.0.0.0:8001`, can you access it on port 8001 from the remote host? Also, try another port with SimpleHTTPServer, like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8002`. This may require additional debugging and more information than just placeholders (for example, what kind of setup/IP addresses are you using). If you can't solve the issue, feel free to [contact me](http://phihag.de/) via mail or instant messaging tomorrow (CEST).

Comment: so I restarted the computer, then restarted it again and now it works.   So I guess the problem is fixed.  I'll see if it comes up again in the future before I instigate more.  Thanks for the help @phihag

Answer (score 2):

The code looks to be correct, so your problem lies elsewhere (perhaps a firewall issue or dns problem for "my_ip").